# Hosts are not being picked from the Inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to perform tasks in the playbook for the hosts mentioned in my inventory file which are grouped under "Jira" But for some reason my group is not being identified to pick. for the content of the files please look below.

How can I run all the tasks mentioned in the playbook with all the hosts in the inventory?

I have an Inventory file with the below contents: Hosts.yml

```
all: # the all group contains all hosts
  hosts:
    ansible:
      ansible_host: #{ansible-controller}
      ansible_user: root
    crowd:
      ansible_host: #{crowd}
      ansible_user: root
    jira:
      ansible_host1: 53.31.54.56
      ansible_host2: 53.31.54.55
```

I have playbook with content:

```
---
- name: Install Jira Application
  hosts: jira
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - ansible-preparation
    #- jira-applicationsetup
```

I always get below error message:

```
    root@sedcagse0550:/usr/Anil/InfraAutomation/gsep-infrastructure-automation : ansible-playbook jira-fullinstall.yml
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: jira


PLAY [Install Jira Application] *************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
```

How can I perform all the tasks to all the hosts mentioned in the inventory file?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, people come here of their own accord to provide answers to good questions. (Repeated) begging using "Can anyone please" in a post doesn't help doesn't make your question more easy to understand. As [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) indicates: only use *relevant* tags (otherwise you might as well include `python`, `ascii`/`utf-8`) as that will just cause others to waste time when searching for those and finding your (non-relevant) question when searching.

Answer (score 2):

You should run the ansible-playbook with inventory parameter(-i) like this:

```
    ansible-playbook -i Hosts.yml jira-fullinstall.yml
```

Otherwise, ansible checks the default inventory file location which is "/etc/ansible/hosts".

If your Hosts.yml already in that location, check your inventory file. In [Ansible 2.7 User Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) YAML inventory files look like this:

```
all:
  jira:
    hosts:
      53.31.54.56:
      53.31.54.55:
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correct, Your inventory file should look like as below::

```
 ansible: # Group Name
   hosts:  
      ansible_host: #Host name
        ansible_user: root  # Host Variable
 crowd:
   hosts:
      ansible_host: #{crowd}
        ansible_user: root
 jira:
   hosts:
      ansible_host1: 
        ansible_host: 53.31.54.56
      ansible_host2: 
        ansible_host: 53.31.54.55`
```

[Please refer this link for detailed formatting about yaml based inventory](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/hosts.yaml)

Comment: I tried it but no use.. i stil face the same problem.

Comment: are you passing inventory file while running anisble play?